# I want to sort everything after fifth line

Tags: sort

I have a list of something that I want to sort it, but like I said after fifth line...

Right now I'm using this (*it will sort everything*):

```
cat file.txt  | sort > sortedfile.txt
```

Comment: It is unclear what happens with the first six lines of the original data. Should that remain or be discarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want line 6 upwards, use

```
 tail -n+6 file | sort
```

if you want line 1 - 5 untouched, and then sorted residual lines, try

```
{ head -n5; cat | sort; } < file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR<6{print $0;next}{print $0| "sort"}' file.txt > sortedfile.txt
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562423/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-header-lines-in-a-unix-sort